# Broken Network Settings Upon Boot

Tags: boot, networking, mount

I have enjoyed using Xubuntu 14.04 since Jan 2016, and thought it was more reliable than Windows 7, UNTIL today. For the past 2 days I was having trouble with Dpkg and had to reinstall Multiarch, and then the Software Center failed to load. NOW, Upon booting, I get the following error message in a window:

```
Failed to apply Network Settings.
Org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.PermissionsInvalid: The permission of the setuid helper is not correct. 

You might not be able to connect to the Bluetooth network via this machine.
    OK.
```

My internet is via Ethernet to ATT Uverse modem. Up until today, it has always connected and worked flawlessly with Xubuntu. Win7 seems to work with it OK too. BUT, I can't do ANY updates until I can restore the Network Settings to connect to the Interweb.

Also, my external USB drive will NOT mount. I suspected the USB ports aren't working, but if that's the case, then my wireless mouse/keyboard dongle wouldn't work either. But they work, so I can't explain why the USB drive will NOT mount. I really need it to mount so I can backup all my stuff for prep to do a fresh clean install upgrade to 16.04. I'm assuming it has something to do with the Network settings.

So, **why won't the Network Settings startup right?** Why won't the USB drives MOUNT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I rebooted in Recovery Mode from the Grub menu on bootup. I selected the root terminal mode. In there, I put in @Terrance code given:

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
```

then did this code to check if the change was made:

```
ls -al /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
```

It showed it was now

```
-rwsr-xr-- 1 root messagebus 310800 Nov 25 2014 /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
```

which, after rebooting MOUNTED all my USB drives, which I took advantage of and backed up all my data. BUT, it still showed the Network was Disconnected.

Since last night, I have been trying to install a fresh clean install of 16.04.1 LTS, BUT now am faced with even MORE errors, of which I will post in a NEW question.

Answer (score 5):

`Org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.PermissionsInvalid: The permission of the setuid helper is not correct.` usually indicates that the permissions for the dbus are incorrect.  Run the following command and check your permission for the file:

```
ls -al /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
```

You should see something very similar to the following.  Make sure that the permissions are the same:

```
-rwsr-xr-- 1 root messagebus 42992 Apr  1 10:41 /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper*
```

If the permissions are not `-rwsr-xr--` run the following command to fix the permissions:

```
sudo chmod 4754 /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
```

or

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
```

Then for good measure, fix the ownership if it is incorrect as well:

```
sudo chown root:messagebus /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
```

Try a reboot after permissions and ownership are changed.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: I try that. NO CHANGE. After I did the 
'll /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper' 
- the output gave me "dbus-daemon-activation-helper service.to.activate".
The other codes seemingly did nothing.

Comment: @hienz1 What was the output of the `ll /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper` command?

Comment: @hienz1 I edited my answer because the ll command should not return what you wrote.  It's supposed to be just a listing of the helper file.

Comment: OK, here's the output:
`-rwxr-xr-- 1 root messagebus 310800 Nov 25 2014 /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper`

Comment: @hienz1 Yep, those permissions are incorrect.  I put the fix in my answer here.  The `sudo chmod` line should fix it.  You can either reboot or try restarting the dbus.  I recommend the reboot.

Comment: I also tried your code,`sudo chmod 4754 /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper` and also `sudo chown root:messagebus /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper` and then rebooted. NO CHANGE as before. Short of whacking it with a hammer, what else can I do?

Comment: @hienz1 So, running those commands and it still shows those permissions?  You can try one other line and see if it fixes it.  I added it as an or to my answer.

Comment: I don't see it. How do you restart the Dbus?

Comment: @hienz1 Oops, I guess it helps if I click save on my changes.  The line is `sudo chmod u+s /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper`.  Unfortunately, the commands that are supposed to restart dbus do not work on 16.04.  The only way is to reboot.

Comment: I did the code given above. NO CHANGE as before. I'm still using 14.04.5 LTS, cause I need to get the USB drives working so I can backup everything. USB drives will NOT mount. Is there a way to force them to mount?

Comment: @hienz1 The only other way I can think of is to boot the host to recovery mode and run those commands.  It probably is not updating because the file being in use.  But the permissions have to go to `-rwsr-xr--` and right now your permissions are at `rwxr-xr--` which is why it is failing.

Comment: I'll try using the install disc to boot into, then use the "Try Ubuntu" install to get to a terminal, then put in those codes. Hold on to your potatoes. Oh wait !!! I can boot in recovery mode from the Grub menu. I forgot about that.

Comment: First ran `sudo chown root:root /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper`. Then `sudo chmod u+s /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper`. Restarted Ubuntu and no more error. Thank you!

Comment: This solution worked for me. The issue showed up when I started working with LXD and Docker, doing install and uninstals on the same day, dealing with containers and etc. OS release: VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)". No restart needed.