# Help with system file permissions, chmoded everything -R and go!

Tags: permissions, chmod

I accidentally, on purpose, changed my entire computer to

```
chmod -R a+rwX /usr
```

Using the command

```
sudo chown -R :users your_directory
```

Just to change permissions for a folder in Stellarium for a project (very overkill!)

You can literally watch me make this fatal mistake here

http://www.twitch.tv/tricam_irl_casts/v/535423391?sr=a&t=4182s

Now I have an error

```
Failed to apply Network Settings.
Org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.PermissionsInvalid: The permission of the setuid helper is not correct.
```

So now I have an unlocked Linux MX computer with missing permissions on basically everything.  Which is kind of ironic to me.

Might I mention that this is my first week using Linux at all!  Learning so fast!

I replied to a confusing conversation about this same issue 2 years ago but I'm guessing it is dead... it confused me, so I'm bringing it up as a new query.

Please be nice to me, I'm new here :)

Old question and my response

[Broken Network Settings Upon Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826619/broken-network-settings-upon-boot)

I literally Googled how to change a folders permission as a user and it gave me a shortcut code to unlock all permissions for the entire computer so everything was working perfectly when I wanted to modify some system files in a program but then when I turned my computer off of course I came up with the same Bluetooth networking Wi-fi error that the permissions had been changed so now my computer works perfectly fine I just can't connect to the internet unless I have an Ethernet which I don't have because this is 2020 so now I have to reset all my permissions for my entire user file how do I do this easily? Or how do I do this at all or should I just give up and restart and reinstall everything?

Seeing as this post is a couple of years old I'm not very confident that anybody will respond so very promptly so I'll keep searching the internet tonight and hoping for an easy hand."

Thanks for any & all help!

A 40yo Linux Virgin.

[Editing root permissions to edit Stellarium files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jklP2.jpg)

[Will chmod or chusr things work?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3Sq6.jpg)

Comment: This indeed is a fatal error that will require you to reinstall the OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I just recursively chmod'd everything under / to 750. Any tips?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154409/i-just-recursively-chmodd-everything-under-to-750-any-tips)

Comment: If your actual question is "how can I modify system files programmatically and not mess up my system like this" the solution to that is (limited!) `sudo`

Comment: In brief, boot from a live USB stick or similar and mount the messed up drive. Salvage anything you can by copying somewhere; ideally the stuff you want to save should all be your personal files in your home directory and the rest of the system can safely be wiped and then you can restore the copied files.

Comment: Sounds like a simple fix, backup & reinstall... just wondering if there is a simple "restore" option for system permissions

Comment: No, save yourself the hassle and reinstall from scratch.

Comment: @Jos Thanks! My father suggested the same, aswell as an upgrade!... now i just have to try and get it on dvd lul